# DB2 connection issue in python after change and update of SSL

Tags: python, db2

I am trying to establish a connection to DB2 which was working fine but after the change and update of SSL, it gave this error: **com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientException: [jcc][t4][2034][11148][4.27.25] Execution failed due to a distribution protocol error that caused deallocation of the conversation. A DRDA Data Stream Syntax Error was detected. Reason: 0x3. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=-58009**. Despite I had updated the cert and did the set up of the connection settings and connection was ok, the codes are giving this error. Can anyone help to advice where did I miss out or anything wrong with my script pls.

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, run
import jaydebeapi
from project_lib import Project

project = Project.access()
abc_connection = project.get.connection(name="abc")

abc_connection = jaydebeapi.connect('com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver', 
'{}://{}:{}/{}:user={};password={};'.format('jdbc:db2', 
abc_credentials['host'], 
abc_credentials['port'], 
abc_credentials['database'], '/project_data/data_asset/ssl_cert.crt', 
abc_credentials['username'], 
abc_credentials['password']))

curs = abc_connection.cursor()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your jdbc connection string for SSL / TLS must look like: `jdbc:db2://host:port/database:sslConnection=true;sslCertLocation=/full/path/to/cert_file;user=...;password=...;`. Note that port for SSL connections is different from port for non-SSL connections. Moreover, you have 7 `format` parameters and 6 `{}` strings - check for such a error when you construct correct connection string...

Comment: Thanks @MarkBarinstein! I will take note of such errors in the future. :)